# Codeigniter 3: inner join results in ambiguous variable name to be used in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

There are several tables, among which `posts` and `categories` which stores the posts categories.

Every post belongs in a category:

[image: Every post belongs in a category]

Category names:

[image]

I want to display the posts with the name of the category each post belongs to. For this purpose, in my posts model, I have the flowing code:

```
public function get_posts($limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.cat_id = categories.id', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

The code above "translates" in

```
`SELECT * FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `posts`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 12`
```

and, if I do `print_r($data['posts'])` it ambiguously returns the post category name as `[name] => Showbiz`.

This forces me to use this ambiguous line in the posts view:

```
<p><?php echo $post->name; ?></p>
```

I want to be able to use this line instead:

```
<p><?php echo $post->post_category; ?></p>
```

In other words, I want this, but with Codeigniter 3 syntax:

```
`SELECT *, categories.`name` as post_category FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `posts`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 12`;
```

and still e able to make use of Codeigniter's ORM feature.

Note: in the controller I have:

```
$data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @Razvan Zamfir, You requirement was not clear

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda I want to use `<?php echo $post->post_category; ?>` in the view.

Comment: post_category is the column name?

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda No, `name` is the column in the `categories` table storing the *category names*. And I do not want to use `<?php echo $post->name; ?>` but `<?php echo $post->post_category; ?>` instead.

Comment: what is post_category?

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda Nothing, and that is what I want to fix. In other words, I want an alias with Codeigniter specific syntax. Keep in mind that CI3 has ORM and I use it extensively in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a `select` and use alias `as` for the category column name statement as shown below. So, now you will be able to `echo $post->post_category;`

```
<?php 

public function get_posts($limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->select('posts.*,categories.name as post_category');
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.cat_id = categories.id', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('posts.*, categories.*');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->join('categories','posts.cat_id= categories.id','INNER');
$this->db->where('posts.id',2);
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.